# Answer deletion second opinion

Tags: support

I've answered [this question](https://chess.stackexchange.com/q/42322/33019) with below, and it was deleted. I don't have much to say except to ask for a second look, as it appears the moderator hasn't read my answer past the first line. And, if their decision is agreed upon, I'd like a rule cited from this network that shows deletion, not downvoting, is the appropriate action, because that's not how the rest of Stack Exchange operates.

[image]

Comment: Note to Readers:  It appears the OP has [posted an answer](https://chess.stackexchange.com/a/42337/26335) that restates it is Zermelo's Theorem (already found in other answers).

Answer (score 7):

This was the question:

> What is this thought called? Is there a name of this hypothesis or theorem or idea?

The answer "Zermelo's Theorem" was given by Matija Sirk. You made no attempt whatsoever to answer the question and instead tried to enter into a debate with the OP.

Comment: Ok, I can edit that in. I don't see why such extreme measures are necessary. "no attempt whatsoever" is blatantly false, and I've no clue where you see "debate".

Comment: I submitted an edit.

Comment: I won't "accept" this answer and I solved the problem another way so this Q&A serves no purpose and should be deleted.